# Liferay redirect to user's entered page post login

Tags: liferay-6.2, liferay-hook

I have created a **custom landing page hook** in Liferay6.2.

Suppose user enters **abc.com/xyz**. Then after login he should not be redirected to my custom landing page. Instead he should be **redirected to xyz post login**.

**My landing page** should be selected only when he enters **abc.com**
How to implement this.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more.

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari. I have created a post login hook that redirects me to a specific page whenever I login. Whether I have entered abc.com/xyz or abc.com it will always redirect to a particular page. I want this hook to work only for abc.com and when I enter abc.com/xyz i should be redirected to xyz and not to that custom landing page.

Comment: are abc.com and abc.com/xyz page urls?

Comment: yes these are page urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fetched using below code in your PostLogin Hook

```
LastPath lastPath = (LastPath) session.getAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH);
```